# Can splice()/tee() be made to work with sockets, and not merely pipes?

Tags: linux, pipe

On Linux, the system calls splice(2) and tee(2) are used to transfer data between two file descriptors. One or both of the file descriptors must be a pipe, according to documentation. Why? Can this be made to work with sockets? Does it work currently, or would kernel modifications be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now they just splice pipe buffers together; socket buffers (on Linux) are different animals, and drag kernel networking into it.  Limiting it to `AF_LOCAL` sockets would simplify implementation at the cost of complicating validation — and you still probably have to deal with them being allocated and mapped via the network buffer management subsystem instead of from anonymous file buffers.